# Плавное перемещение блоков на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код для фиксированной шапки, в первом положении блок находится за контейнером, после прокрутки страницы на 100px добавляется класс где шапка становиться фиксированной и находится уже в контейнере.

Как можно задать блокам движение, чтоб они не телепортировались в контейнер а плавно подъехали?

Фиксированная шапка:

```js
function ensure_sticky() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лови пример! Ну один из вариантов, если я правильно понял задачу.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else {
      $('.header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.sticky {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  animation: anim 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header {
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
 transition: all 3s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    top: -100px;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header" id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```